# Same images being cached even if already loaded (background slideshow)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple background slideshow with an image preloader. I'm loading images into a new array then changing background url every n seconds. Even when all the images are loaded it keeps on adding same images into browser cache like they weren't loaded. I'm wondering if there's a way to avoid it and what's the reason for that?

seems like it works in Firefox but not in Safari or Chrome
[TEST](http://bit.ly/1vKguO0)

```
var images = new Array();
var imagePaths = [ 
"img/pic1.jpg",
"img/bic2.jpg",
"img/pic3.jpg",
"img/bic4.jpg"
];

var cnt = 0;

function imagesloaded(){
cnt++
if (cnt >= imagePaths.length){
    window.alert('all loaded!');
    changebg();
}
};

for(var i = 0; i < imagePaths.length; i++) {
var img = new Image();
img.src = imagePaths[i];
images[i] = img;

images[i].onload = function(){
    imagesloaded();
}
}

var i = -1;

function changebg(){
$('#container').css({background : 'url(' + images[i++].src + ')'});
    if (i == images.length) {
        i = 0;
    }
}
setInterval(changebg, 1000);
```

Comment: how can you tell it's adding more images to the cache?

Comment: seems like it works in Firefox but not in Safari or Chrome (i edited my question)